# Xamarin Form: How to apply NamedSize.Medium to OnIdiom element

Tags: xaml, xamarin, styles, font-size

I can change the font size by passing values to OnIdiom Element for different device. But how do I pass FontSize Medium to the OnIdiom in xaml, what is the TypeArguments to passed into.

```
<Style x:Name="normalFont">
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
        <OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="Small" Android="Small" />
            </OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="Medium" Android="Medium" />
            </OnIdiom.Tablet>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I know it won't be double what type should I put.

Answer (score 1):

I did it in Xaml.cs file attached with  xaml 
in Constructor add this

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
    {
      normalFont.FontSize=Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small,typeof(Style));
        }
        else if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)
        {
            normalFont.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Style));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

put

x:TypeArguments="NamedSize"

instead of

x:TypeArguments="x:Double"

Comment: Use x:TypeArguments="NamedSize"  instead of x:TypeArguments="x:Double"

Comment: Error XLS0504 Property 'FontSize' does not support values of type 'OnIdiom (NamedSize)'

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how you must do it.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122883/error-setvalue-can-not-convert-large-to-type-system-double-when-using-style-with-onidiom

Basically, you must create a MarkupExtension to handle the conversion.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.